# gradlew installdebug shows The syntax of the command is incorrect

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, gradle, gradlew

I am new Android Development, I run my apps through [gradlew installdebug](https://androidride.com/efficient-way-to-make-apk-and-reduce-android-build-time/) using this link. It was working fine. But now CMD shows 
`The syntax of the command is incorrect. 
<component name="libraryTable">`

I had checked there is no mistake in syntax.

Actually, how to avoid this problem and run like before??

Comment: try `./gradlew installDebug`

Comment: it doesn't work